# PHP - wamp hiding my page extension causes errors in pages links

Tags: php, wampserver

I have a project almost done on **appserv** then I migrated to **WAMPServer** but my projects got a lots of errors (i'll fix it) but the real problem is my websites main menu links.

my way to open pages is :

```
index.php?p=myacc
```

now in wamp the link called like this :

```
index?p=myacc
```

how do I resolve this problem

Comment: Have you got a .htaccess with some kind of url rewrite going on? Or maybe you forgot to move the .htaccess file?

Comment: You need to update htaccess file